# Unsure if I need SSL or alternative

Tags: php, security, curl, ssl

I have a website that does not currently have SSL (due to cost reasons). It has a login form, which is why I believe I need SSL. However, I don't actually store any passwords, only usernames; My login form grabs the POSTed username/password and sends it via cURL to an https-secured login form, which then returns a yes or no, so to speak, to my server.

Given this, is an SSL certificate absolutely necessary, or is there a lower-cost alternative to securing my form?

Comment: SSL protects data as it travels between the client and the server, why would the fact you don't store it matter?

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary - but make sure your users know that the data they send you is not protected.

Comment: Without SSL, you're still transmitting the username/password in plaintext between the user's browser and your server

Comment: SSL doesn't really have anything to do with storing data but more with the safe transmission of data. I would say that the type of project you are working on should influence your decision on whether you purchase a certificate or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using TLS, the username and password are exposed to anyone listening in on the traffic.

This is a problem, because even if your website is "low value", and it doesn't matter if attackers are able to steal other people's credentials, people *reuse* passwords.

So by not protecting your website, you are exposing your users to unnecessary risk. Attackers can learn usernames and passwords, and try and re-use those credentials for their {email,bank,work,etc} accounts.

As others have pointed out, SSL/TLS protects data in motion, not data at rest. The fact that you don't have any sensitive stored data isn't relevant to the decision of whether to protect your traffic.

As Elon points out, you can get low assurance free TLS certs which are significantly better than nothing.

Remember to serve at least the entire login page over HTTPS, or there's no point in doing it at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to add SSL support.

You can get SSL cert for free from here https://www.startssl.com/ (it's trusted cert so user will not see warning message as he'll see with self-generated cert).